# MapView not showing annotations

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm working with MapKit for the first time, trying to make a simple app that shows all the nearest thrift stores. I don't really know how to work with annotations and have just been searching through the apple documentation and trying to implement their examples. I thought that this code would work, but it still isn't.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    var coordinates: [String] = [""] //latitude, longitude
    var firstTime = true
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("View loaded...")
        theMap.delegate = self //this doesnt crash though so ig the iboutlet creates an instance
        locationManager = CLLocationManager() //gotta create instance of class first. else it crashes
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var theMap: MKMapView!
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if firstTime {
            firstTime = false
            theMap.isHidden = false
            let myLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]
            let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: myLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: myLocation.coordinate.longitude)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, latitudinalMeters: 5000, longitudinalMeters: 5000)
            theMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            theMap.showsUserLocation = true
            print("Setting the center of the map...")
            
            let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
            searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "thrift store"
            searchRequest.region = theMap.region
            
            let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
            search.start { (response, error) in
                guard let response = response else {
                    return
                }
                
                for item in response.mapItems {
                        let annotation = MKPlacemark(coordinate: item.placemark.coordinate)
                        self.theMap.addAnnotation(annotation)

                        
                    
                }
                }
                
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation{
            return nil;
        }else{
            let pinIdent = "Pin";
            var pinView: MKPinAnnotationView;
            if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: pinIdent) as? MKPinAnnotationView {
                dequeuedView.annotation = annotation;
                pinView = dequeuedView;
            }else{
                pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: pinIdent);

            }
            return pinView;
        }
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
             didFailWithError error: Error) {  print("Error fetching location") }
}
```

I've only tried some of the example code in the Apple documentation and haven't messed around with it much because I'm still very new to Swift (ab a month of experience) and am unfamiliar with these frameworks.

Comment: `I thought that this code would work, but it still isn't` is not an appropriate error description. Do you get an error? What does work, what not?

Comment: Start by simplifying your solution. You don't need core location to show annotations on a map; add the annotations and scroll the map manually if required to view them.  The next step is to get location permission so that you can show the user's location on the map and center the map on the user. MapView can do this for you. Writing code in `didUpdateLocations` is the wrong approach here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't ask the user for the necessary location permissions from `info.plist`. So `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations location: [CLLocation])` doesn't called.

In the info.plist add `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description` in `Information Property List`